# Is there way to combine as and in SQL Server

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-like, sql-in

```
select ptidentifier, patientname, patientage, patientcreditcards
from patients with (nolock)
where ptidentifier like '%3026737%'
```

Let's say I have like 20 different patient identifier, in order to an like, I need to insert one at a time, is there way to do it combining `in` and `like`? So I can search multiple patientidentifiers at same time?

I use as because the patientidentifier is not exactly like the 302673, since that's all the info that was provided to me.

Comment: Are you merely looking for `where ptidentifier like '%3026737%' or ptidentifier like '%12345678%' or ...`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
where ptidentifier like '%123%' or
      ptidentifier like '%456%' or
      . . .
```

Your code looks like SQL Server, so here is another method:

```
select p.*
from patients p
where exists (select 1
              from (values ('123'), ('456'), . . .) v(identifier)
              where p.ptidentifier like '%' + v.identifier + '%'
```